# MS Fakes - Access base class members of stub

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, stub, microsoft-fakes

Is it possible to mock out the members of a base class in a stub? For example, if I have:

```
public class MyObjectBase {
    public virtual int GetNumber() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class MyObject : MyObjectBase {

}
```

Then I want to be able to write a test that does this:

```
void MyTest() {
    var stub = new StubMyObject();
    stub.GetNumber01 = () => 2; // this line won't compile
    Assert.Equal(2, stub.GetNumber());    
}
```

But, `GetNumber01` doesn't exist on `StubMyObject` because it's a member of the base class.

EDIT:
After removing the fakes assembly and re-adding it, this problem goes away. Looks like it was just a problem with the fakes assembly not getting updated.

Comment: What is the error and why is the stub function called 01 ?

Comment: The error is that GetNumber01 cant be found on StubMyObject. The delegate is called GetNumber01 because, if it were called GetNumber, then it would conflict with the actual method GetNumber(). So, by default MS Fakes appends "01" to the name.

Comment: For me it works... And the base class method is found without issues (in VS2013RC and VS2012upd4RC. Have you tried removing the fakes file and the reference from your project under test and re-added it? Syntactically there is no issue.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I deleted the fake file and reference, re-added them, and it worked.